# How to flag Tags without posting them in meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

I note that a user has created a Tag with no attached wiki titled "[Emergy](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergy)".

This raises the question of rigour, as the term itself is ill defined - that is not my question here.

When flagging the question isn't necessary, how can we flag the Tag (Without raising this in meta every time)?

- This question has been edited after (and as a result of) EnergyNumbers' answer being published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to flag a tag, then raising it on meta is the right thing to do usually.

It is in this case, as the tag spans more than one question. And if a tag isn't **obviously** bad, then raising it on meta is the right thing to do, to air the debate.

If a tag appears on only one question, and it's obviously bad, then flag the question for a moderator's attention, using a custom flag

Emergy is a pretty messy concept, but I'm tempted to let it live, for now, as Odum still has some adherents out there.

Comment: I genuinley thought it was a typo. Turns out it's a poorley defined qualitative conflation of ill defined variables. Following or not, unless it can be clearly defined, if I get a vote, then I say kill it. Doesn't answer the more general aspect of the question about raising flags for Tags, but +1 for the info though.

Comment: I'll edit the question to reflect what your answer taught me.

Comment: Scarily, some people do do *quantitative* emergy analysis. I do not hold it in high regard.

Comment: Touchee for edit. I'll  wait the customary 24 hours, and thanks.